# Web login system

Tags: php

So here is my problem: I am designing a website for my project.  So a user has got a role, stored as user_role in my database.  User roles can be classified as 'police', 'ambulance', 'SMF' or 'fire'.  So if the user logs in as 'police', he will be redirected to a specific page and if a user logs in as smf, he will be redirected to another webpage and so on.  I am not able to get the proper syntax for logging in through user roles.

Is it possible for me to some suggestions on the php scripts that i can use??

Thank you in advance

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask), [What have you tried?](http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/), and [How To Ask Questions The Smart Way](http://catb.org/esr/faqs/smart-questions.html).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just have a home page for every role like

```
police       police_home.php
ambulance    ambulance_home.php
smf          smf_home.php
fire         fire_home.php
```

After you checked the users credentials just relocate him to his role-based home page:

```
header("Location: ".strtolower($user["role"])."_home.php");
exit;
```

Comment: Ok thank you.  my problem is that, it should redirect to the webpage as soon as the user clicks on the login button.  So do i have to use onclick or any code of that sort or will it get redirected as soon as the user clicks on log in??

Comment: Do you check the credentials with PHP or with Javascript? You would normally have a `<form action="login.php" method="post">` and an input for username and password and a `<input type="submit" />` button. The user submits the login form to your PHP-script by pressing the submit-button; no onclick required. You then check his credentials and to a HTTP 301 Relocate.

Answer (score 1):

Compare the input data obtained by using select query in DB with where condition as username=username , password= pasword and usertype= usertype

if all conditions are true then redirect to desired page

```
select * from users WHERE username = $_POST['username'] AND password = $_POST['password'] AND user_type=$_POST['user_type']
```

if Query yields any result you just need to chk it in if loop and redirect to the page desired, if found any record.

**NOTE: I have note written detailed code for your exercise**..

Comment: Haha, http://bobby-tables.com

Answer (score 1):

1. have a database that has

   - username
   - password
   - user_role
2. create a login system. you can find a lot of these on the internet
3. when the user logs in check the role assigned
4. have a config file/ database table / key-value array that matches the user's role to their respective homepage
5. then use a header redirect to redirect them to their page